# Facebook canvas app dialog redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

Wanna execute user-to-user request dialog initiated by server side.
On my FB canvas application I have button "invite my friends". After user presses it, the POST request goes to my server and i redirect to FB request dialog using the following C# MVC code:

```
return Redirect("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=MY_APP_ID&message=MESSAGE&redirect_uri=MY_APP_CANVAS_URL");
```

What i'm getting on Facebook canvas instead of "select users" dialog is the blank page with the FB logo href-ed to target page. How do i this confirmation to disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook typically doesn't allow for the content of a canvas page to be one of their dialog URLs. The way most developers work around this is to issue a client-side redirect to an absolute URL that redirects the entire page, instead of just the canvas iframe content.

For your purposes, you can achieve this by serving a minimal page as the response to the POST request that contains the following markup:

```
<script>
    top.location="<%= (insert apprequest dialog URL here) %>";
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, yesterday i've found solution like this and it worked. By the way do you think specifying "display=iframe" parameter for my initial redirect url can help doing this? I tried but was getting 191st error "redirect_uri doesnt belong to your app domain"..